# How do I setup the Facebook SDK in Android Studio 1.0.0? Getting SDK Location not found error

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk, gradle

I tried importing the sample, but I got an error saying

"Error:(1, 0) SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable."

I then tried importing the Facebook SDK module into a blank activity. I can't seem to get it working. If not the error above, it has a strange gradle error. I spent hours trying to fix it, but no luck.

Please note that I'm very new to Android and I'm not even sure how to handle the gradle things. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is not very fast in my opinion. Im using Eclipse which is better i think. I never did use android studio much but lets see if this works it is used in Eclipse.
Right click on your libs. Add the facebook sdk. Right click on the facebook sdk. Then build path. Im not sure if this qill work for Android atudio since its made by the same company who made IntelliJ. JetBrains.

Comment: I don't think that you can do those exact steps in Android studio. I tried creating a libs folder and putting the SDK in, but nothing happens.

Comment: Look for the project properties and look for java build libraries or something close to it. When you first create your project did it not ask you to use an sdk? If it didnt you must add it manually somewhere in your project properties.